# create list programmatically with tags from character vector

Tags: r

I am probably going to knock my head against the table because its obvious but how do you create a list programatically from a character vector such that the character vector provides the tags and a nother vector the values. E.g.

```
character.vector <- c('first.element', 'second.element')
values.vector <- c(1, 2)
a.list <- list(//magic here//)
print(a.list) // prints the same as list(first.element=1, second.element=2)
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
character.vector <- c('first.element', 'second.element')
values.vector <- c(1, 2)

as.list(setNames(values.vector, character.vector))
```

Comment: nice! exactly what I needed. Didnt know the setNames function and will use it extensively from now on! :-D

Answer (score 6):

You could set:

```
   > names(values.vector) <- character.vector
   > values.vector
     first.element second.element 
                 1              2
```

and, of course, convert it into a list if necessary:

```
> as.list(values.vector)
$first.element
[1] 1

$second.element
[1] 2
```

Answer (score 5):

The other answers covered it better, but just for completeness, another way would be to construct the expression you want to evaluate using `parse` and use `eval` to evaluate it....

```
# tag and values for list elements
tag <- c('first.element', 'second.element')
val <- c(1, 2)


content <- paste( tag , "=" , val , collapse = " , " ) 
content
# [1] "first.element = 1,second.element = 2"

eval( parse( text = paste0("list( " , content , " )" ) ) )
# $first.element
# [1] 1
#
# $second.element
# [1] 2
```

Answer (score 5):

Surprised that noone's mentioned `structure`:

```
structure(as.list(values.vector), names=character.vector)
```